# jq: group input and produce grouped raw output

Tags: json, key, grouping, jq

Consider the following JSON input:

```json
[
    {
        "g": "g1",
        "k1": "v11",
        "k2": "v12"
    },
    {
        "g": "g1",
        "k1": "v21",
        "k2": "v22"
    },
    {
        "g": "g2",
        "k1": "v31",
        "k2": "v32"
    }
]
```

I would like `jq` to produce the following output:

```
g1
v11 v12
v21 v22

g2
v31 v32
```

My attempt with the jq command:

```sh
jq --raw-output 'group_by(.g) | .[] | {g: .[0].g, v: .} | "\(.g)\n\(.v[].k1) \(.v[].k2)\n"'
```

Produces incorrect results:

```
g1
v11 v12

g1
v21 v12

g1
v11 v22

g1
v21 v22

g2
v31 v32
```

Link to jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/w81t2OW9iO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand each group only once.

```
group_by(.g)[] | .[0].g, (.[] | "\(.k1) \(.k2)"), ""
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_YSNymVriw)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A more generic alternative :

```
jq --raw-output 'group_by(.g)|
        map(.[0].g as $g | del(.[].g) |
             [$g] + map(
                 [.[]] | join(" ")
             ) | join("\n")
        ) |
        join("\n\n")'
```